# how to make the code in Sublime text 3 in one line?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

when I code using sublime the code breaks up (without hitting enter) when it goes to the end of the frame of sublime software ... I want the code to be in one line.

[Here is what I want ... see this image to know what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAfyf.png)

[Here is what I don't want ... see this image to know what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmvJR.png)

I want the second image to be like the first one so when I code the code should be in one line unless I hit enter

Comment: %APPDATA%/Sublime Text 3/Packages/

Comment: thanks ... but the first reply is much easier

Comment: okkkkkk........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is click on menu `View` ->  `Word wrap`, i.e. uncheck it

Comment: Click again to uncheck